# How JavaScript Program Can Communicate With C# Console Application?

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm trying to write a program that is composed of two parts. The logic part that I prefer to write in C# language because it's object oriented and more important it's the language witch I know the best among objective languages, and the graphic part witch I want to write it with Html, Css and JavaScript and again because they're the most familiar graphical languages witch I can use. Now my question is that how can I transfer data between a C# console app and a JavaScript browser app.
Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**:

I must clarify that I just need C# console app and not a web app or web api, and therefor this part is not a backend project. And I need to run these two program separately and want them to communicate with each other.

Comment: Typically if you have a web front end communicating with a backend you would expose and serve a REST API to have the front end make calls to the backend.  If you need bidirectional communication (push from backend) you could use a socket.  If this is some other type of setup you could also look into [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) schemes like [gRPC](https://grpc.io/).

Comment: Is this JavaScript app going to run in the browser? Or will it be run in some sort of hosted framework like React Native or Electron?

Comment: The JavaScript app will run in the browser

Answer (score 1):

What you describe should be a full stack application to be honest

With ASP.NET you create your C# backend, setup controllers which handle the interaction between backend code and the front end, and then on the front end you can utilize both Razor markup for HTML templating alongside standard Javascript.

With Blazor web apps, you can take it a step further and have your backend code compile to web assembly and execute directly on the client engine, but it also integrates javascript interop as well. Just be mindful about whether you want a client side or server side Blazor app, as each do things a certain way and are meant for different use cases

What you describe though, sounds more precisely like you want a *seperate* javascript app, which should be in communication with an **ASP.NET Web API**. This way you create your backend and api endpoints, which the javascript app can then make requests against. You can start your research for that [with MS's tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

The dotNet command line tools can generate solutions for all of these, an ASP.NET fullstack web app, ASP.NET Web API solution, as well as the various blazor app options. And of course, the standard IDE's like Visual Studio and Rider can create these solutions as well

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have direct interop, blazor might be what you're looking for.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0